# What vinegar acidity is necessary to effectively kill household mold?

Tags: mold

I have 30% and 5% and I'm guessing it's somewhere in between.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, this is off-topic in this "Home Improvement" stack. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about Home Improvement.

Comment: @DanielGriscom  I'd say killing household mold  is pretty much a home improvement. That is,  unless you want the OP to wait until it ruins  their walls and then ask how to fix them. :-) .. stay safe.

Answer (score 1):

5% appears to be adequate per a brief search of the web.

30% is not really "vinegar" anymore - call it acetic acid and treat with care.

I have seen 10% sold as "cleaning vinegar" but I don't find any results in a quick search indicating it's much more effective than undiluted 5% on mold.

Answer (score 0):

I've used white vinegar which runs about 7% and it's worked great for surface and below surface mold whereas bleach is only good for surface mold. if you've really got vinegar that's 30%, I'd handle with care and get rid of it.

Comment: Dilute (adding acid to water) and use is a perfectly acceptable way to "get rid of" 30%